# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder`

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

When I am injecting `DbContextOptionsBuilder` to `CustomTicketStore` in ASP.NET core 3.1. I am getting an exception message

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.ITicketStore Lifetime:
> Scoped ImplementationType: OneIAM.Services.CustomTicketStore': Unable
> to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder`1[OneIAM.Data.ApplicationDbContext]'
> while attempting to activate 'OneIAM.Services.CustomTicketStore'.)

Below is code from the Startup file.

```
        public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
          ...

          // Persistent ticket/cookie store to provide durable user sessions
          services.AddScoped<ITicketStore, CustomTicketStore>();
          var optionsBuilder = GetDbContextOptionsBuilder(services);

          services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
          {
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.SessionStore = new CustomTicketStore(optionsBuilder);  <=
          });
        }

        private static DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext> GetDbContextOptionsBuilder(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            using (var scope = services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope())
            {
                return scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>>();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you can share your `CustomTicketStore`.

Comment: @YiyiYou I haven't added much in `CustomTicketStore`. Just adding `constructor` with `DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>` parameter. I am getting this error on `dotnet run`.

Comment: @YiyiYou However you can take reference from this [link](https://ml-software.ch/posts/implementing-a-custom-iticketstore-for-asp-net-core-identity) for `CustomTicketStore`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,I test your code,and find it will reproduce your error with `services.AddScoped<ITicketStore, CustomTicketStore>();`
And here is my CustomTicketStore:

```
public class CustomTicketStore: ITicketStore
    {
        private readonly DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext> _optionsBuilder;
        

        public CustomTicketStore(DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext> optionsBuilder)
        {
            _optionsBuilder = optionsBuilder;
        }

        .......
    }
```

And I find if  I add a constructor without parameters to CustomTicketStore,it will work:

```
public class CustomTicketStore: ITicketStore
    {
        private readonly DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext> _optionsBuilder;
        public CustomTicketStore()
        {
        }

        public CustomTicketStore(DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext> optionsBuilder)
        {
            _optionsBuilder = optionsBuilder;
        }

        ........
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @YiyiYou. It is working for me without injecting service `services.AddScoped<ITicketStore, CustomTicketStore>();` also but not getting `User (ClaimsPrincipal)` after that means at home page so unable to load user.

Comment: I mean you can add `public CustomTicketStore()
        {
        }` to `CustomTicketStore`,you don't need to delete `services.AddScoped<ITicketStore, CustomTicketStore>();`

Comment: Tried both way, but not getting `'user' (var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);)`  value as null.

Comment: You can check if  you  save data to context and save it correctly to database.

Comment: After I spent couple of hours, I got to resolve the issue. Thanks @YiyiYou